# Thunderbird/Firefox fonts problem

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, fonts, thunderbird, mozilla

I am using Xubuntu 16.10. Not so long time ago Mozilla products (Thunderbird and Firefox) stopped using system fonts in Xfce but all other programs work well with system fonts.

```
Firefox - v.53.0
Thunderbird - v.52.0.1
```

[image]

Could somebody advice how to force them to use system font?

Comment: Did you set the desired font in FF and TB?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. But all GUI elements still uses own fonts with such solution.